# Use iOS category to create new Color

Tags: ios, categories, uicolor

I would like to create some new `UIColor`s that are used in my app throughout.  From time to time the RGB is slightly tweaked (the exact color shade is being debated)

Currently I have to create the new colors from RGB and the code is sprinkled all over and repeated.

Is there a better way where I can create a new color one and use that through out my app.

```
[UIColor myNewCustomRedColor]
```

What is the best pattern here - is Category the right choice - if so how?  If no -what is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 9):

Category is a good choice for something like this. I usually just make a new .h/.m pair of files, `MyCategories.h`/`MyCategories.m`, that contains commonly used categories that you want everywhere.

MyCategories.h:

```
@interface UIColor (MyCategory)

+ (UIColor *)customRedColor;

@end
```

MyCategories.m

```
@implementation UIColor (MyCategory)

+ (UIColor *)customRedColor {
    return [UIColor redColor];
}

@end
```

You can either import the .h file wherever you need it, or you can stick the import in your MyApp-Prefix.pch file.

Comment: I'd only add that it is a good idea to name category files as <Class category extends>+CategoryName - For example UIColor+CustomColors, I find it very useful for organizing projects.

Answer (score 5):

One approach I've used on other projects is to create a ProjectStyle.h file, that has #defines for custom colors and other style related constants.  You just need to import it.

Something like:

```
ProjectStyles.h

#define RED_HEADER_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8f green:0.1f blue:0.1f alpha:0.9f]
#define RED_BACKGROUND_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9f green:0.3f blue:0.1f alpha:1.0f]
#define PRIMARY_FONT [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12.0f]
```

You could also have a corresponding .m file if you wanted to create constant instances of some UIColor or UIFont objects, something like

```
ProjectStyles.m

+ (UIColor *) redHeaderColor 
{  return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8f green:0.1f blue:0.1f alpha:0.9f];  }

+ (UIColor *) redBackgroundColor 
{  return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9f green:0.3f blue:0.1f alpha:1.0f];  }

+ (UIFont *) primaryFont
{
    static UIFont *font = nil;
    if ( font == nil )
        font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12.0f];
    return font;
}
```

And then of course expose those in the header

The other thing I like about a ProjectStyle kind of approach is that after a while you will want more custom things than just colors - custom fonts, custom line and shadows.  Having a Style class or header to place all these things in gives you one place to look up what custom elements are already defined for all sorts of things, and a very obvious #import for later coders to follow back to you centralized well of custom information.

If you just place custom elements in categories then you end up with customization spread over several categories, and also the possibility (mostly remote) of category name collisions with other third party libraries.

Comment: WWDC 2012 session 216 presents a very similar approach to this, if anyone is interested.

Comment: While using some stylesheet alike pattern seems appropriate, I would always refrain from using preprocessor directives for such task - defines are not type-safe and hence ugly. Why not using a proper appearance attributes (like color) factory. Something like `[MyAppearance color:@"ultraBlue"]`

Comment: #define is type safe, because they end up being real code that is checked by the static analyzer and debugger in the same way any other code would be (so somewhere if you use a #define that results in a UIColor, but needs a CGColor you will get an immediate warning).  The editor also autocompletes off the #define code, so MY_COLOR.CGColor autocompletes.  Also, #define items autocomplete wholly - in your example you'd still have to type in @"ultraBlue" which leaves room for error.  Using either #define or factory methods the styles should easily autocomplete to eliminate error.